# Extracting data from a webpage where an unusual tag format is used

Tags: powershell

Note:  has to be done in powershell. 
I have searched and searched and have this one little problem that I can not seem to solve.
The page is in an unusual form of xml, and looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<string xmlns="http://foo.bar.moo.org/">WILBER</string>
```

This is the only thing on the page.  the only part that will ever change is WILBER might be something else.

I have tried:

```
$site="http://lalaland.org/Getmoocow?input=$foo_name"
$data = (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString($site)
$foo = [regex]::Matches($data, '<string.*?>(.+)</string>') | % {$_.Captures[0].Groups[1].value}
```

and a few varients but no luck.  the only thing I need is is what is located between the string tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, given the string that you presented,

```
[xml]$x = @"
>> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
>> <string xmlns="http://foo.bar.moo.org/">WILBER</string>
>> "@
>>
$x.string.'#text'
WILBER
```

Comment: I have a feeling that this is not the entire string that you are getting back though.

Comment: yeah.  I tried your example worked great, however, when I actually tried it from the web page, it gave me  version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" as the string.  any idea how to get the wilber?

Comment: Not sure why it would do that. Updating the question with the string that you *actually* get from the page would help.

Comment: that was basically the same thing I was getting in IE, except I changed the http value. But I was able to get your example to work in my case by first downloading the page into a file then running it. after that it worked great.

My major issue is the little piece of information is from a database I do not have access to, so the person that does gave me a way to get it using the Get method.  I asked if there was a way to just get the value I needed, but he said no, that was the only way it was available....  yeah..  anyway thanks for your help.